# Rails Client_side_validation error message is not generating on turbolinks:load

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks, client-side-validation

Rails Client_side_validation error message is not generating on turbolinks:load but generates on page load (page refresh).

Rails Version: Version 4.2.6
Client_Side_Validation: Version 4.2.7

Model:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :content, presence: true

  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Form:

```
<%= form_for [@post, @post.comments.build], validate: true do |f| %>

  <div class="input-group">
    <%= f.text_field :content, class: "form-control", autocomplete: :off %>
    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <%= f.submit "Send", class: "btn btn-primary pull-right" %>
    </span>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

Generated HTML:

```
<form data-validate="true" novalidate="novalidate" class="new_comment" id="new_comment" action="/posts/21/comments" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="ZmpADuX73JqNvAh5wljYCmk68wXioVLFP1YDHY+71l4YADgQglKiQAODBrc5OrXvioqurjI5/JwqfO2qJXPPvg==" />

  <div class="input-group">
    <input class="form-control" autocomplete="off" type="text" name="comment[content]" id="comment_content" />
    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Send" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" />
    </span>
  </div>
</form>

<script>
//<![CDATA[
if(window.ClientSideValidations===undefined)window.ClientSideValidations={};window.ClientSideValidations.disabled_validators=["uniqueness"];window.ClientSideValidations.number_format={"separator":".","delimiter":","};if(window.ClientSideValidations.patterns===undefined)window.ClientSideValidations.patterns = {};window.ClientSideValidations.patterns.numericality=/^(-|\+)?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:\,\d{3})+)(?:\.\d*)?$/;if(window.ClientSideValidations.forms===undefined)window.ClientSideValidations.forms={};window.ClientSideValidations.forms['new_comment'] = {"type":"ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder","input_tag":"\u003cdiv class=\"field_with_errors\"\u003e\u003cspan id=\"input_tag\" /\u003e\u003clabel for=\"\" class=\"message\"\u003e\u003c/label\u003e\u003c/div\u003e","label_tag":"\u003cdiv class=\"field_with_errors\"\u003e\u003clabel id=\"label_tag\" /\u003e\u003c/div\u003e","validators":{"comment[content]":{"presence":[{"message":"can't be blank"}]}}};
//]]>
</script>
```

Issue:

The generated input HTML should look like this:

```
<input class="form-control" autocomplete="off" type="text" name="comment[content]" id="comment_content" data-validate="true" />
```

`data-validate="true"` is not generating on `turblinks:load` but generates ok when the page is refreshed.

Does anyone know of a solution for this?

Comment: You can remove or off turbo links if you don't needed it.

Comment: Hi @ShefaleeChaudhary, thank you for your comment. I would like to keep turbolinks on.